# Dash? Graph does not display? Dataframe issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to make a line graph with dash that takes a user input and will search a dataframe for a match, however it does not seem to work, code below:

```
  app = dash.Dash()
    app.layout = html.Div(children =[
    
    html.Div(children='''
    Search:
    '''),
    dcc.Input(id='input', value='', type='text'),
    html.Div(id='output-graph')
    ])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='output-graph', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='input', component_property='value')]
    )
def update_graph(input_data):
    df = df5.fillna(0).loc[:,input_data]
    
    
    dcc.Graph(
    id='example-graph-2',
    figure = {
        'data':[{'x':df.index, 'y':df[0:], 'type': 'line', 'name':input_data},
               ],
        'layout':{
            'title':input_data
        }
    })
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

where df has been defined earlier. Something like;

```
zzz = input('Please enter a name:')
df4 = df5.fillna(0).loc[zzz]
```

works fine, so I am not sure why the code above does not work.

the final line from the traceback is :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jul/2020 01:10:45] "POST /_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

but no graph is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Your callback function is lacking a return statement.

Just add "return" before "dcc.Graph"

```
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='output-graph', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='input', component_property='value')]
    )
def update_graph(input_data):
    df = df5.fillna(0).loc[:,input_data]
    
    
    return dcc.Graph(
    id='example-graph-2',
    figure = {
        'data':[{'x':df.index, 'y':df[0:], 'type': 'line', 'name':input_data},
               ],
        'layout':{
            'title':input_data
        }
    })
```